# What is wrong in this where condition?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
ALTER PROCEDURE EditEmployee (

@RefNo integer ,
@EmpId nvarchar ,
@Name ntext ,
@Designation ntext ,
@Qualification ntext ,
@Gender ntext  ,
@DOB date ,
@Address text ,
@Email ntext ,
@Phone decimal )
        as 
        begin
        UPDATE  Emp_Sample 
        SET RefNo=@RefNo,Name=@Name,Designation=@Designation,
            Qualification=@Qualification,Gender=@Gender,
            DOB=@DOB,Address=@Address,Email=@Email,
            Phone=@Phone
           where EmpId=@EmpId

       END
```

Comment: are the type of EmpId and @EmpId same?

Comment: what problem are you facing?

Comment: @MillerKoijam yes, It is the same

Comment: @VigneshKumar none of the rows are affected when executed.

Comment: @user3256231 What's error ?

Comment: @SurajSingh none of the rows are affected when executed.

Comment: @user3256231 Please check the answer ,try specifying size of `nvarchar` as it's default size is 1.

Comment: I could mention some other issues. Phone should not be decimal. If a number starts with 0 it will be removed. You are using ntext where you should be using nvarchar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include `@EmpId nvarchar` size .

```
ALTER PROCEDURE EditEmployee (

@RefNo integer ,
@EmpId nvarchar(30) ,

nvarchar [ ( n | max ) ]
```

When n is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration statement, the default length is 1. When n is not specified with the `CAST` function, the default length is 30.

[HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have [Cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) Problem

Try like this

```
WHERE EmpId = CAST(@EmpId AS INT)
```

Comment: but EmpId has been declared nvarchar by default

Comment: @user3256231 May i know its values?

Comment: EmpId=E92. Is this what you wanted??

Comment: @user3256231 Yes make sure that you have data with that ID and you are passing the same ID in@empID